# How can I pair the contents of this array without repeating itself?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am trying to make a Secret Santa code, so that upon running the program, it will take all names from the array and pair them.

I've tried numerous ways of doing this but it just ends up repeating an entry already in the output. fOr example:

Fred and Sarah

Yusef and Kyle

Sarah and Fred

Sarah has come up twice which is not good.
Here's the starting code, of course I first randomise the array, but have no clue what to do after that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] students = {"Fred","Mary","Yusef","Kyle","Sophie", "Lydia", "Max", "Donald","Yasmin","Archie"};
        string[] shuffleStudents = students.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();



    }
}
}
```

Any ideas, can anyone help?

I have also tried this which I thought would work but it returns an error of the index being out of bounds of array

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] students = { "Fred", "Mary", "Yusef", "Kyle", "Sophie", "Lydia", "Max", "Donald", "Yasmin", "Archie" };

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string[] shuffleStudents = students.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();


            Console.Write("{0} and {1}", shuffleStudents[count], shuffleStudents[count+1]);

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {

                count++;
            }
        }


        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are many many good posts here which show how to do an actual, proper shuffle.

Comment: You should share the code for some of your previous failed attempts so we can remark on why the issue happens.

Comment: @cost I added one of my attempts in

Comment: @Ateeb, have you tried generating random numbers and use it as the index of your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to shuffle them, then print the result. Here's the code I did:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace _05_01_19_5am
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            String[] students = { "Fred", "Mary", "Yusef", "Kyle", "Sophie", "Lydia", "Max", "Donald", "Yasmin", "Archie" };

            var shuffleThem = students.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(shuffleThem[i] + " + " + shuffleThem[i+5]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, you should use `shuffleThem[i+5]` instead of `shuffleThem[i+1]`

Answer (score 0):

Fiddled around a bit more and found the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        string[] students = { "Fred", "Mary", "Yusef", "Kyle", "Sophie", "Lydia", "Max", "Donald", "Yasmin", "Archie"};
        string[] shuffleStudents = students.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Your pairs for Secret Santa has been completed!");

        int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {

                Console.Write("{0} and {1} \n", shuffleStudents[count], shuffleStudents[count+1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                count++;

            }
        }


        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}